# Wrapping Javascript function in IIFE doesn't work with video player

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have some code that created a video player. When wrapping the script in an IIFE the video player part doesn't work, but the rest of the code works. There aren't any errors in the condole either.

Fiddle"
https://jsfiddle.net/wdbnmhrm/

JS

```
(function() {

var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  var video_div = document.getElementsByClassName("easy-yt-bkg")[0];
  var video_url = video_div.getAttribute("data-youtube-id");

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('easy-youtube_background', {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      playerVars: {
                autoplay: 1,
                loop: 1,
                controls: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                autohide: 1,
                modestbranding: 1,
                vq: 'hd1080'},
      videoId: video_url,
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    player.mute();
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
       player.playVideo(); 
     }
  }

  var height_adjustment = video_div.offsetHeight
  video_div.posiiton = "relative";
  video_div.zIndex = -10;
  var content_div = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0]
  content_div.zIndex = 1;
  content_div.position = "relative";
  var height_change = "-" + height_adjustment + "px"
  console.log(height_change);
  content_div.style.top = height_change;
})();
```

html

```
 <div id="easy-youtube_background" class="easy-yt-bkg" data-youtube-id="ZZ9_RJ2EPo0"></div>
<div class="content">Some cool content goes here</div>
```

css

```
#easy-youtube_background {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  }

  .content {
    color: red;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are never calling your `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` function.

I reordered things a bit to make them more readable and got rid of the stuff you don't need to recreate this problem.

```
(function() {
    var player;
    var video_div = document.getElementsByClassName("easy-yt-bkg")[0];
    var video_url = video_div.getAttribute("data-youtube-id");

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('easy-youtube_background', {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        playerVars: {
          autoplay: 1,
          loop: 1,
          controls: 0,
          showinfo: 0,
          autohide: 1,
          modestbranding: 1,
          vq: 'hd1080'},
        videoId: video_url,
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.playVideo();
      player.mute();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
         player.playVideo(); 
       }
    }

    var ytScript = document.createElement('script');
    ytScript.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    ytScript.onload = function() {
      YT.ready(onYouTubeIframeAPIReady);
    };
    var scriptContainer = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    scriptContainer.appendChild(ytScript);
}());
```

Comment: This is the first time I'm using YT.Player and couldn't find information about about it. I noticed I wasn't explicitly calling onYouTubeIframeAPIReady, but it was firing without the IIFE. Perhaps from a callback after the script loaded? You solution worked! Thanks!